# Is it safe creating system file on a website

Tags: php

I've created test file which shows ip address phpinfo some kind information it's working now like site.com/test.php reachable from outside do you think it's secure to have such as this? i wanna know if it has any risk from outside because i read some kind of stories with test files and wanted to get some opinions from you.. I mean especially from outside someone can't trick my test file isn't it ? lets say i am getting ip address or any other variables might cause kinda and dangerous something.

> System Test
>
> ```
> <body>
> <?php 
> echo "PHP Version: ".phpversion().'<br>';
> echo "Dosya Yolu: ". getcwd().'<br>';
> echo "Temp Yolu:".sys_get_temp_dir().'<br>';
> echo "Max Execution Time : ".ini_get('max_execution_time').'<br>';
> echo 'Sistem Tarihi Saati: '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
> var_dump(class_exists("SOAPClient"));
>
> echo '<-SOAP Client Yüklü mü?<br>'; 
>
> if(function_exists('oci_connect')) {$oracle = 'VAR';} else { $oracle = 'YOK';}
> echo 'Oracle bağlantısı için oci_connect '.$oracle;
>
> if(function_exists('fopen')) {$fopen = 'EVET';} else { $fopen = 'HAYIR';}
> echo "<br>fopen çalışıyor mu? ".$fopen;
>
>
> //$b = is_writable( "/xml_temp" ); //boolean value
> //echo $b; print_r($b);
> //echo "<br>xml_temp yazılabilir mi? ".$b;
>
> ## Test if cURL is working ##
> ## SCRIPT BY WWW.WEBUNE.COM (please do not remove)##
> echo '<br>CURL TEST';
> echo '<pre>';
> var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'));
> var_dump(curl_version());
> echo '</pre>';
> echo 'Curl Yüklü mü?'.var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'));
> echo 'CURL TEST SONU <hr>';
>
>
>
>
>
>
> $_SESSION['deneme'] = 'evet';
>
> echo 'Session çalışıyor mu? '.$_SESSION['deneme'];
>
>  if (extension_loaded('mcrypt')) {echo '<br>mcrypt yüklü';}
>
> else {echo '<br>mcrypt yüklü değil';} 
>
>
> if( function_exists( 'mcrypt_module_open' ) ) {echo '<br>mcrypt yüklü';}
> else {echo '<br>mcrypt yüklü değil';}
>
> //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> function get_server_memory_usage(){
>
>     $free = shell_exec('free');
>     $free = (string)trim($free);
>     $free_arr = explode("\n", $free);
>     $mem = explode(" ", $free_arr[1]);
>     $mem = array_filter($mem);
>     $mem = array_merge($mem);
>     $memory_usage = $mem[2]/$mem[1]*100;
>
>     return $memory_usage;
> }
>
>   // See http://www.whatismyip.com/automation for the exact URL
>   echo '<br>Çıkış IP:'.file_get_contents("http://ip.appspot.com/");
>   echo '<br>server IP:'.$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
>
>   echo '<br>Magic Quotes Durumu: ';
>   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {echo 'Magic Quotes Aktif';} else {echo 'Magic Quotes Pasif';}
>
>
>
>
> function get_server_cpu_usage(){
>
>     $load = sys_getloadavg();
>     return $load[0];
>
> }
> echo '<br>Memory Usage:';
> get_server_memory_usage();
> echo '<br>SERVER  Usage:';
> get_server_cpu_usage();
> ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
>
>   // See http://www.whatismyip.com/automation for the exact URL
>   echo '<br>Çıkış IP:'.file_get_contents("http://ip.appspot.com/");
>   echo '<br>server IP:'.$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
>
>  echo '<br>GD eklentisi yüklü mü? (imgsize.php icin gerekli)';
>  if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
>     echo "GD yüklü";
> }
> else {echo 'GD yüklü değil';}
>
>
>
> /*
> echo '<br>PORT KONTROL<br>';
>
> $host = 'stackoverflow.com';
> $ports = array(21, 25, 80, 81, 110, 443, 3306);
>
> foreach ($ports as $port)
> {
>     $connection = @fsockopen($host, $port);
>
>     if (is_resource($connection))
>     {
>         echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' ' . '(' . getservbyport($port, 'tcp') . ') is open.</h2>' . "\n";
>
>         fclose($connection);
>     }
>
>     else
>     {
>         echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' is not responding.</h2>' . "\n";
>     }
> }
>
>
> echo "DNS çözümlemesi<br>";
>
> $result = dns_get_record("php.net", DNS_ANY, $authns, $addtl);
> echo "Result = ";
> print_r($result);
> echo "Auth NS = ";
> print_r($authns);
> echo "Additional = ";
> print_r($addtl);
> */
>
> phpinfo();
> ?>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: I would not recommend to expose such information to the public. If this file is so important for you why not protecting access to it with Basic Auth?

Comment: Given that this information should hardly ever change, you shouldn't need to have it there for longer than a few minutes to begin with. But putting that aside, it does expose a lot of information about your system. Is that a vulnerability? Hopefully not, as most of that information can probably be *guessed* in the first place, and even with that information, an attacker shouldn't have any more attack surface than without.